# Issue with SQL Insert query using POST and PHP

Tags: php, json, post

Essentially I have the following PHP script that I am trying to use for Inserting new records into my database.

When hard coding values in the PHP script to insert everything works as it should, put when I use the POST method, the values are never written to my database. The following my script:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$customer = $_POST['customerName'];
$manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturerName'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$serial = $_POST['serial'];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO Equipment (customer, manufacturer, model, serial)
VALUES ('$customer', '$manufacturer', '$model', '$serial');";

if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Can you please check whats in the $_POST variable ?

Comment: Also post the html content .

Comment: Can you please show your html code.

Comment: after you find the problem, perhaps fix the massive SQL injection security hole you have.

Comment: Not sure why you are using mysqli_multi_query here. Why not just mysqli_query for starters. Then you need to look into validating your inputs. And what Tim said above.

Comment: Can you please show me the proper way this can be written? I am fairly new to php

Comment: did you check your `$_POST` values before `insert`?

Comment: @M.Hemant Yes of course, is there a better way to write what I have?

Comment: remove a single quote from `$sql` query like `($customer,$manufacturer)`

Comment: If you post the html code may be someone will fix your code.

Comment: @M.Hemant strings must be quoted in a query.

Comment: There is no HTML code, I will be using this script with a mobile app written in Swift

Comment: I am testing it using Postman with no result

Comment: that's the kind of information that should have been in the original post .. Add `print_r($_POST);` to the top of the page, and let us know what it returns

Comment: It returns: `Array ( )`

Comment: well, that's the problem. you're not posting anything to the script

Comment: Then why did you write `Yes of Course` as my question? there must be an issue of missing `name` attribute

Comment: from my vague memory of using postman there is a dropdown selector for POST,GET,PUT etc, are you sure you have `POST` selected?

Comment: @M.Hemant My apologies, I misunderstood your question

Comment: @tim Yes i am using the `POST` option

Comment: well, you're not actually posting to the file, that's a simple fact. I can't help any more.

Comment: I understand that now, but I can't seem to figure out why that is

Answer (score -1):

I just tested this all out.  Your PHP code works as it is.  To see the variables coming in from the post, you can add:

```
var_dump( $_POST );
```

at the top of your code.  That will show you that the stuff coming in is correct.  The HTML that I used to make this work is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="post.php" method=POST>
        Customer: <input type="text" name="customerName"><br />
        Manufacturer: <input type="text" name="manufacturerName"><br />
        Model: <input type="text" name="model"><br />
        Serial: <input type="text" name="serial"><br />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

Note that the names of the inputs are exactly as the names you're expecting in the PHP.

Additionally, you should do some kind of sanitizing in the variables as you receive them, otherwise, you're vulnerable to all kinds of SQL injection.

One simple way to do this is to use addslashes().  Like this:

```
$customer = addslashes( $_POST['customerName'] );
$manufacturer = addslashes( $_POST['manufacturerName'] );
$model = addslashes( $_POST['model'] );
$serial = addslashes( $_POST['serial'] );
```

That won't completely save you, but it's better than nothing.  Anyway, I have it working using your exact PHP and the HTML I posted above.

Comment: Using your html the record is created successfully but for some reason using postman I keep getting array (0)

Comment: In postman I have it set to `POST` and `Body` and `x-www-form-urlencoded`